# Sort keys in a dictionary Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a Json file like this:

```
{
  "wasGeneratedBy": {
    "_:wGB3": {
      "prov:entity": "ivo://stsci/DSS-digitized-J.444",
      "prov:activity": "stcsiNum-1b"
    },
    "_:wGB1": {
      "prov:entity": "ivo://stsci/DSS-digitized-J.444-cutouts",
      "prov:activity": "cds_cutout444"
    },
    "_:wGB2": {
      "prov:entity": "ivo://stsci/DSS-digitized-I.444",
      "prov:activity": "stcsiNum-1a"
    }
  },
  "activity": {
    "stcsiNum-1a": {},

  },
  "used": {
    "_:u6": {
      "prov:entity": "ivo://stsci/DSS-Plate-R.444",
      "prov:activity": "stcsiNum-1c"
    },
    "_:u2": {
      "prov:entity": "ivo://stsci/DSS-Plate-I.444",
      "prov:activity": "stcsiNum-1a"
    },
    "_:u3": {
      "prov:entity": "ivo://stsci/DSS-digitized-J.444",
      "prov:activity": "cds_cutout444"

  },
  "entity": {
    "ivo://stsci/DSS-digitized-R.444": {},
    "ivo://stsci/DSS-digitized-J.444-cutouts": {},
    "ivo://stsci/DSS-Plate-R.444": {},
  }
}
```

But I want to sort all the keys ("wasGenereratedBy","activiy"...) in a specific order like this ("activity","entity","used","wasGeneratedBy")

I have declared this:

```
my_own_order = ['entity', 'used', 'activity','wasGeneratedBy']
```

And I have try this, but doesn't work:

```
print sorted(fileName,order=my_own_order)
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks you

Comment: You need OrderedDict: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

print OrderedDict((k,mydict[k] for k in  my_own_order))
```